# Homeomorphism between $\mathbb R^n - \mathbb R^m$ and $(\mathbb R^{n-m}-\{0\}) \times \mathbb R^m.$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to show that:

$$\mathbb R^n - \mathbb R^m = (\mathbb R^{n-m}-\{0\}) \times \mathbb R^m.$$

Then, I tried to see what happens in the case where $n=3$ and $m=1$, i.e,

$$\mathbb{R}^{3}-\mathbb{R}=\{(x,y,0), x,y \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } x,y\neq 0\}$$

But I can't define the [homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism).

Can someone help me?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^{3}-\mathbb{R}\ne\{(x,y,0), x,y \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } x,y\neq 0\}.$ Try first with $n=2,m=1.$

Comment: How are you defining $\Bbb R$ as a subset of $\Bbb R^3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your left hand side shouldn't be written $\mathbb{R}^n-\mathbb{R}^m$ but $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus(\{0\}^{n-m}\times\mathbb{R}^m).$
It is really *equal* to your right hand side, as a subspace of $\Bbb R^n.$
There is nothing to prove.

Answer (score 2):

If you include $\mathbb{R}$ inside $\mathbb{R}^3$ as $\{(0, 0, z) \mid z \in \mathbb{R}\}$, then $\mathbb{R}^3 - \mathbb{R} = \{(x, y, z) \mid (x, y) \ne (0, 0)\} = \{(x, y) \mid (x, y) \ne (0, 0) \} \times \{z\}$.

Comment: Why the downvote?